# countdown time in android studio

Tags: android, countdown

I want to run the service when the countdown time has finished, but when I exit the application the command does not work, what's the solution?

**time.java**

```
private void startTimer() {
        
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateWatchInterface();
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), alert1.class));
        }

    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
    updateWatchInterface();
}
```

this is the service class
**alert1.java**

public class alert1 extends Service {

```
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try{
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("RELAY1_STATUS");
                myRef.setValue("OFF");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

        }, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. First, send your counter time as a parameter. When time finished just start your service.

```
private void setTimerForStartService(int timeInMillis){
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeInMillis, 1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60);
                updateCountDownText(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateWatchInterface();
                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), alert1.class));
            }
        }.start();
    }
```